# Ajax form post not binding to object in ASP.net core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I cannot figure this out.  I have similar code in other areas of my project that works fine. What am I missing?

Why is studentDTO object null?

***The Controller Action***

```
[HttpPost("SaveStudent")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveStudent(
    [Bind(Prefix = "Student")][FromForm] StudentDTO studentDTO
)
{
     // blah blah
}
```

***The Class***

```
public class StudentDTO 
{
    public Guid StudentID { get; set; }
    public Guid AccountID { get; set; }
    public int TuitionID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualTuitionCost { get; set; }
    public int TuitionMonths { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

***The AJAX call***

```
var formData = $("#addEditStudentFrm").serialize();
console.log(formData);

$.ajax({
    url : '/api/blah/SaveStudent/',
    dataType: 'json',   
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        // blah blah
    },
    error: function (result) {
        // blah blah
    }
});
```

***The Request***

[image]

I am hitting the controller action, but I'm not getting the form data. Suggestions?

If I remove `[FromForm]` I get a response of "***415 Unsupported Media Type***"

I have been using the information provided here to no avail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: A POST is on sending side, GET is on receiving side.

Comment: I'm trying to POST the data so I can save it in the DB.

Comment: Where is the StudentDTO come from?  Are you using the correct instance?  It looks like it comes from a form.  What fills in the form when app starts?

Comment: Model binding is essentially supposed to create an object of that typed based on the form data posted.

Comment: If you are using the same instance of the form that contains the data.

Comment: do you think you need to prefix `'Student_`

Comment: Son of a biscuit.  I figured it out.  I was using `Student_` instead of `Student.`  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Prefix needed to be `Student.` and not `Student_` in the name attribute of the form elements:

[image]